# How can I use JWT to transfer some data to another domain

Tags: laravel, session, jwt

Good day, all. I am fairly new to and learning about web tokens. I am building a laravel application and I have a piece of data (value amount) that id like to transfer to another domain. I'd like to use a JWT to transfer this amount, Can anyone assist me with how I could achieve this. As I mentioned before, I am a noob and would appreciate any help. Thank you!.

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen JWT for this?

Comment: I'm doing a payment system and the API I'm sending the amount to works with tokens. So I'd just like to send a token containing the amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value amount looks like it should not be part of a JWT. Such a token is primarril used to prove that the client/user using it with at request to a server can prove that he is authenticated. It is further used to transfer information about the client/user that the server requires to further authorize the user. Such information could be a list of roles the client/user has or an organization he belongs to. One could imagine a value amount like the maximum credit the user has. Such data could perhaps be part of a JWT. But I don't think this would be good design.